# Some weird error in npm saying it needs "readable-stream"

Tags: node.js, npm

Whenever I run npm this shows up:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js:48
    throw err
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\are-we-there-yet\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\ours\index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
    at tryPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:436:19)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:678:18)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\are-we-there-yet\lib\tracker-stream.js:3:14)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\are-we-there-yet\\node_modules\\readable-stream\\package.json',
  requestPath: 'readable-stream'
}
```

Can someone help, I've looked it up, repaired and reinstalled nodejs but nothing is working?

I was just trying to install discord.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstal Node.js in Control Panel and go in C:\Program Files and delete nodejs folder there are still some files after you delete it. Then istall it again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue couple days ago.. That means there is a missing file in nodejs folder for some reason i do not know why.. Therefore i download nodejs windows binary (. zip) file in the link below :
https://nodejs.org/en/download/
And extract the zip in
Program files/nodejs
It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, I had to uninstall Node, delete npm in C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm and delete npm cache in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache
Then I reinstalled Node and it worked.

Comment: Same issue, same answer as the previous answers on this question.